# Inline code in RadListview on data

Tags: asp.net

How do I use code on an 
    Text='<%# Eval("PickPrice") %>'
if I fx would like to say PickPrice * 2 or if I received a date as string and would like to subtract it from today?

Trying to combine <% ... %> with the <%# .. %> 
 from looking at here:
http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Text='<%# double.Parse(Eval("PickPrice").ToString())*2 %>'
```

For the date, you can do something like:

```
Text='<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("TheDate").ToString()).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0:N}", (Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("PickPrice")) * 2)) %>';
```